# Change of pictures in JLabel

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jlabel, imageicon

First of all, I'll show the code and then say where the problem is :

I have a class that extends JFrame. In it's constructor there is a fragment
that allows to load an image into JLabel :

```
    try
    {
        repaint = ImageIO.read(new File(ReturnPageName(0)));
    }catch (IOException e) {
    }
    image = new ImageIcon(repaint);
    imageLabel = new JLabel();
    imageLabel.setIcon(image);
    imageLabel.setVisible(true);
    add(imageLabel);
    setUndecorated(true);
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(1024, 600);
```

After pressing certain button such code should be processed :

```
SetMenuImage(1);
 try {
    Thread.sleep(10000);
 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
SetMenuImage(2);
```

Where the function looks like that :

```
public void SetMenuImage(int number)
{
 try
    {
        repaint = ImageIO.read(new File(ReturnPageName(number)));
    }catch (IOException e) {
    }
    Graphics g = repaint.createGraphics();
    g.setFont(font);
    g.setColor(black);

    image = new ImageIcon(repaint);
    imageLabel.setIcon(image);
    revalidate();
    repaint();
}
```

There problem is that only the second image is loaded ('2'). The program goes into both functions but only the second one changes the JLabel. If I replace them ('2' goes first, then followed by '1') then '1' is shown. What might be the cause of such problem and how to overcome it ?

Thanks in advance for Your help :)

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example). 2) **Don't block the EDT, the GUI will freeze up.  Instead use a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.**

Comment: Thanks a lot :D I searched a little info about SwingWorker. What I did was creating a SwingWorker which in his doInBackGround function was waiting a little and loading second image. It worked ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are freezing the main thread during that duration. If you read [this](http://www.scs.ryerson.ca/~mes/courses/cps530/programs/threads/Repaint/index.html) you will see that:

> repaint() does not invoke paint() directly. It **schedules** a call to an intermediate method, update(). Finally, update() calls paint() (unless you override update).

`repaint()` is **asynchronous** so it does not necessarily repaint the screen (i.e. call the `paint()` method) before you call `sleep()`. Therefore. when you freeze the main thread, you freeze the gui, and the gui is not repainted. Instead, use [javax.swing.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) (not to be confused with java.util.Timer).

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for usage.

---

UPDATE:

It appears you have solved your issue already following [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/). Just putting it here for the benefit of future readers.

Comment: The answer is correct and to the point, however I would dispute the usefulness of the link you posted. It references docs from Java 1.4 (!!!) with broken links. Some things can be done better in newer versions of Java/Swing. Also, Ryerson is not widely known outside Canada, so most people will just see a plain-text site on a nondescript address. A reference to one of Oracles guides would suit this answer a lot better.